# GitHub Organizations for a project spanning multiple repositories?

Tags: git, github, organization, repository

I've started a project that involves at least three repositories on GitHub.

One of the repositories is a generic documentation-and-examples dump, and the other two contain the implementation of two programs that form the backbone of the project.

Should I use a GitHub Organization to handle such a configuration? 
 Or should I just dump it all to my own account, along with a dozen other, completely unrelated repositories?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Short answer ...

Start out with the repositories in your personal account. From there, if/when things grow and/or get popular with the community, move them to an organization account.

- [GitHub Blog: Repository redirects are here!](https://github.com/blog/1508-repository-redirects-are-here)

---

## Long answer ...

Let's look at some of your options:

### 1. Organization:

For more information on GitHub Organization features, be sure to read:

[GitHub Blog: Introducing Organizations](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations)

> If you've ever had to manage multiple GitHub accounts, desired a company-specific dashboard, wanted to add read-only collaborators, or needed to give someone else administrative control over one of your repositories, you're going to love Organizations.

**Based on your question, I can't say if an Organization is right for you** *(my gut is telling me "no")*, but maybe looking at some real world examples will help you make your decision.

Here are some examples of GitHub Organizations that I find interesting to look at:

1. https://github.com/gruntjs
   This is one of my favorite examples of an open source Organization account. I'm mostly impressed by the naming conventions used for repositories (i.e., essentially [`grunt/`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt) is the main repo and all related core/contrib code/plugins/tasks live in `grunt-xxxx/` repositories).
2. https://github.com/github
   Probably it's worth looking at GitHub's own Org. account. The naming conventions used for the repositories aren't as tight as Grunt's (IMHO), but it's a good example nonetheless. Oh, and now's probably a decent time to point out the ["Members" tab](https://github.com/github?tab=members), as you don't get this for personal accounts or repositories.
3. https://github.com/twbs
   Twitter Bootstrap. I think this is a good example of an Org. account with only a few repositories (note the single repo with 58,000+ stars). Also note that Bootstrap has five members (at the time of writing this), yet those five are responsible for an insanely popular repository ([contrast that to the 214 members of the GitHub Organization](https://github.com/github?tab=members)).

   1. https://github.com/twitter: Twitter's main GitHub account.

A few more general examples:

1. https://github.com/yeoman: Build tools.
2. https://github.com/h5bp: HTML5 boilerplate.
3. https://github.com/nprapps: News industry example.

### 2. Personal account

As you've mentioned already, you could create repositories inside your personal account and go from there.

Will you need collaborators?

[GitHub Help: Collaborating / How do I add a collaborator?](https://help.github.com/articles/how-do-i-add-a-collaborator)

As you can see, adding collaborators is pretty painless.

**Based on your question, this option sounds like the one you want.**

### 3. Repo with multiple branches:

You could create one repository and utilize branches to organize your related bits of code.

**I don't think most folks would agree that this is the best way to organize your code**:

- [Use forever-branches or directories for project related documentation, wireframes, designs, etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857229/use-forever-branches-or-directories-for-project-related-documentation-wireframe)

On the other hand, there's nothing that says you can't organize related bits of code using branches.

One personal annoyance I have with this technique is that GitHub's GUI/interface will show you this message:

[image]

... when viewing branches other than your `master` (that is, if your branch is ahead/behind in commits).

**Tip:** If you're using a more recent version of Git, you can pull specific branches using `git clone -b mybranch --single-branch git://sub.domain.com/repo.git`:

- [Clone only one branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14930421/922323)
- [How to clone a single branch in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920956/922323)

Related:

- [A successful Git branching model (a.k.a., `git-flow`)](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)
- [GitHub Blog: GitHub Flow in the Browser](https://github.com/blog/1557-github-flow-in-the-browser)

### 4. Hybrid approach:

> Should I use a GitHub Organization to handle such a configuration? Or should I just dump it all to my own account, along with a dozen other, completely unrelated repositories?

You could use a combination of all of the above. For example:

1. Setup an Organization for "... generic documentation-and-examples dump, and the other two contain the implementation of two programs that form the backbone of the project".
2. Use your personal account for "... a dozen other, completely unrelated repositories"
3. Use branches for demo pages [`gh-pages`](http://pages.github.com/), related code and/or documentation.

---

#### Note(s):

It's also worth mentioning that you can use a repository's WIKI for documentation purposes:

- [GitHub Blog: Git-powered wikis improved](https://github.com/blog/774-git-powered-wikis-improved)
- [GitHub Blog: Making GitHub More Open: Git-backed Wikis](https://github.com/blog/699-making-github-more-open-git-backed-wikis)