# Appropriate naming for (GitHub) repositories belonging to the same project

Tags: git, naming, github, naming-standards, packages

I have some issues selecting an appropriate naming scheme for GitHub repositories that belong to the same project. The main package repo relies on additional repos to generate documentation or run tests. During development on the local machine, those repositories import one another (located in the same root directory). All those repositories are hosted on GitHub through under the roof of an "organization account" for that package, which contains all repos.

Given this organization, which of the following naming conventions is more practical and efficient:

1. Each subdirectory has the project prefix (e.g. https://github.com/pandas-dev, https://github.com/gruntjs):

   ```
   <project-name>   # GitHub organization account
       <project-name>
       <project-name>-docs
       <project-name>-tutorials   # contains resources for unit tests
       <project-name>-vignettes
   ```

   Pros:

   - better standalone name when cloning single repos and not the whole package ecosystem
   - unambiguous path management when integrating the dependencies during dev

   Cons:

   - seems unnecessarily redundant
2. The repos don't have a common prefix (e.g. https://github.com/numpy, although somewhat mixed naming convention):

   ```
   <project-name>   # GitHub organization account
       <project-name>
       docs
       tutorials   # contains resources for unit tests
       vignettes
   ```

   Pros:

   - seems more intuitive considering usual folder structures

   Cons:

   - not always unambiguous

Related: [GitHub Organizations for a project spanning multiple repositories?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/211673/github-organizations-for-a-project-spanning-multiple-repositories?rq=1)

Comment: This question seems to me a valid questions: two alternatives are envisaged, OP made serous research to find pros and cons and related questions (evidence provided as links). Furthermore there are objective arguments to the choice. Last but not least, it’s useful to the community: many starting project teams/oss communities face the same question. I vote to reopen it.

Comment: I think your question deserves to be reopened. Unfortunately, many naming question happened to be too subjective and this is probably why this one was prematurely closed. Let’s try to fix this.  Maybe you could delete your first comment (I understand what you mean, but it won’t help). Then edit your question with some minor improvement: a short sentence about the context of the repos (open source? large team? company-internal?), and if possible reword “better” into something more specific to your goal?

Comment: By the way, one of your example seems to show very well what happens when people don’t think in advance about this question;-)

Comment: thanks for being constructive Christophe! and sorry for losing patience - I may have seen too many interesting questions (not just mine, fwiw) chopped away for being "opinionated"

Comment: There is a lot of pain in this approach.  Just have a single repository with all the code in multiple modules correctly linked together.

Comment: I agree it is preferable to have a single repo, and it might be sufficient for many/most packages. However, consider the examples I have given: in reality, many projects make use of multiple repositories to not have the complexity crash down on the maintainers. At some point it becomes less pain to split it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues at stake here:

- The directory naming convention: Directories represent a hierarchical organisation: the `docs` in `<project-name>` are in principle the docs related to that project.  Repeating the prefix is redundant, makes renaming difficult.  Moreover it makes practical life more difficult with longer path names (on graphical file browsers, the end of longer names is sometimes hidden behind ... and you need to hover over it to see the full name)
- The repository naming convention:  Repositories are supposed to be self-contained pieces that can be cloned independently.  Here it is important that the name fully and unambiguisly refers to their content, i.e. `<project-name>-docs` including the project name.

The repository logic should in general prevail: distinct repository may be cloned independently (e.g. a technical writer or a translator could have lots of different project-docs folders cloned on her/his local machine). Therefore option 1 - with prefix - would be the way to go (unless you'd work with [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) or want to give additional instructions for manual work).

Comment: thanks, the directory/repo distinction is a helpful way to think about this.

Comment: @mluerig glad that it helped. AndI hope it can help others as well in view of the practical aspects.  I’m always annoyed when I clone repos in my default github directory and one week later have to do extra-research to find out what this “docs” or “datetime" was about. In any case: it’s either extra-steps before (clone into a project directory) or after (check again and again what it was or move to a better place). So I am glad that people like you engineer their repos in advance to avoid such hassle ;-)

Comment: I think the opposite, actually. I want the github structure to look good. Users that clone my repo can do `git clone https://github.com/myorg/myrepo myorg-myrepo`. Basically, you can easily set names for local clones that are different from the remote name. I often do this to disambiguate local clones.